# Sleeping while holding a mutex in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, mutex, sleep

What happens if a process sleeps while holding a mutex? For example, if i have the following code:

```
mutex_lock(mtx);
wait_event_unterruptible_timeout(wait_queue_head, condition, timeout);
//some other code
mutex_unlock(mtx);
```

Is the mutex released while sleeping and re-aquired before the process wakes up? Or does the process keep holding the mutex while sleeping?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The mutex is held.

It says what it does on the tin.

Answer (score 6):

The mutex won't be released while sleeping.

In Linux kernel, you are allowed to sleep while holding an mutex or rw_semaphore. On the other side, you cannot sleep while holding spinlocks or rwlocks

Comment: thank you, another question: what if i call wake_up() on a non-sleeping queue? for example: if I call wake_up(wait_queue_head) after the wait_event_timeout() already timed out? will nothing happen or is it undefiend?